# Saltstack check before using pillar

Tags: salt-stack

Good afternoon, if you can help, I will be grateful, I use saltstack with napalm to automate the cisco configuration in the `/srv/salt/interfaces/` folder there are 2 files `vlan.sls` and `vlan.jinja`, I successfully execute this command from this files when I run, but how to check not applying this config on hardware? Because by default, it immediately applies the change and applies it in `startup -config`. Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is a `test` option you can add, like `test=True` which will show what will actually happen.

Comment: Tried it, but if we give a false command, for example valn 400, with this command we will try to create a vlan, it still returns, ok, no problem, and if we run it, we will return an error.

Comment: If you can update your question with some code, someone here may be able to help.